# iOS - playing a youtube video from a webview thumbnail

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, youtube

Was about to finally submit an app when I realized that the youtube videos I'm playing play from the iPhone, but not the iPad. Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSString *embedHTML = @"\
            <html><head>\
            <style type=\"text/css\">\
            body {\
            background-color: transparent;\
            color: white;\
            }\
            </style>\
            </head><body style=\"margin:0\">\
            <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
            width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></embed>\
            </body></html>";


            NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, [videoItem objectForKey:@"URL"], thumb.frame.size.width, thumb.frame.size.height];
            UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:thumb.frame];
            [videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
            [videoContainer addSubview:videoView];
```

Is there any reason this would work on the iPhone and not the iPad? I'm testing on a 1st generation iPad. The videos play on both iPhone models I've tested (3GS and 4S).

Nothing happens at all when I tap on the webviews on the iPad.

Comment: what is loading in WebView ? What is the height and width of thumb ?

Comment: @MSK If log the webview after creating it I get this: webview: <UIWebView: 0x2ebf00; frame = (10 14; 236 126); I can see a blank white view, and touch/scroll it. But nothing happens when I tap it.

Comment: This is from YouTube API doc "To allow room for critical player functionality, players must be at least 200px by 200px." Also off topic but you should use new iFrame APIs to embed youtube videos.

Comment: @MSK This isn't the player though. This is just a webview to display a thumbnail which will play the video. Do you know of any examples of the iFrame API?

Comment: It works on the iphone, where the frame is much smaller than 200x200. For now I'm using the iframe embed on the ipad, which has it's own limitations, but at least the video plays.